# How to assert the content of the response body in rails 3 functional test

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 3.0.7 application. In the functional test I have following code. I am not using rspec or anything. This is plain vanilla functional test that comes with rails.

```
assert_response :success
```

Above assertion is passing. However I need to assert on the full content that is returned as the body of the response. How do I access the response body?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can access the response body in a functional test via:

```
response.body
```

Often, in this style of testing, you really want to use the method:

```
assert_select
```

A nice way to check out the assert_select API is via the cheat gem:

```
gem install cheat
cheat assert_select
```

Comment: `response.body` will be a json string. If you need to operate on it like a hash then you can use `JSON.parse(response.body)` to get that hash.

Answer (score 3):

This rails testing guide might help you some: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#testing-views